# Ruby on Rails + Active Record: Order, distinct and random in one query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I have the following Active Record models:

```
class Group < ApplicationRecord

  has_many :group_users

end

class GroupUser < ApplicationRecord

  belongs_to :group

end
```

I'm using **PostgreSQL** as my **RDBMS** and **Rails 5.1.1**. I want to retrieve the first `10` groups which have `group_users`, ordered randomly. I also don't want any duplicates (that may exist given that a `group` has many `group users`). However, the following query does not work, and it behaves like the `distinct` isn't there at all:

`Group.joins(:group_users).order("RANDOM()").select("groups.uid, RANDOM()").limit(10).distinct`

Comment: When you say "don't want any duplicates" mean that the groups retrieved shouldn't have a common GroupUser?

Comment: Can `group_users` contain duplicates based on `user_id` and `group_id`? Is that intentional or is there a compound unique index missing?

Comment: Or do you mean that it should not contain duplicate users?

Comment: @PedroGabrielLima I meant that I don't want group duplicates

Comment: @max Our DB schema, doesn't permit duplicates for  `group_users` based on `user_id` and `group_id`. I didn't add the `User` model to my code snippet, but yes, `GroupUser` `belongs` to `:user`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you are selecting `RANDOM()`. Remove it from `select` clause.

Alternatively, try this:

```
Group.where(id: GroupUser.select(:group_id)).select(:uid).order("RANDOM()").limit(10)
```